# Passing in multiple arguments to a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

For the pthreads library, would it be better to use structs or bit fields to pass in arguments to a thread? I want to use less memory in my program when passing arguments to the function.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define FLYABLE 0x1
#define FOODABLE 0x2
#define ALL_OPTIONS 0xFF
/*struct my_ThreadStruct
{
    bool flyable;
    bool foodable;
};*/
void *my_ThreadFunction(void *args)
{
    if (*(uint8_t *)args & FOODABLE)
        printf("Im being eaten!\n");
    if (*(uint8_t *)args & FLYABLE)
        printf("Wee!");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
pthread_t child;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t arguments = ALL_OPTIONS;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, &my_ThreadFunction, &arguments);
    pthread_join(child, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use whatever suits you best. It depends on your use case. Anyway in your example using structs, the memory overhead is totally insignificant.

Comment: "Less memory" is a red herring — do not chase it.  Do what works most sanely (and using bit-fields is usually not the right answer).  If you're seriously memory constrained, are you sure POSIX threads are the correct way to be working?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to use less memory in my program when passing arguments to the function.

Saving 2 bytes (`sizeof(my_ThreadStruct)`) when passing arguments should be the *least* of your problems.

Your goal should be to write the most clear, testable, maintainable and debuggable code you could.

The 2 bytes that you will save with bit packing is *dwarfed* by the overhead of thread creation (which is usually measured in 100s of KiB or more).

Also note that you could do "bit packing" in a clearer way using bit-fields:

```
struct my_ThreadStruct {
  unsigned int flyable: 1;
  unsigned int eatable: 1;
};
```